# Como determinar si una ubicación se encuentra fuera de un rango

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Tengo una app que le envía datos (latitud, longitud, fecha y hora) a un web service. La consulta de datos se realiza a través de una página en PHP, pero necesito saber cuando una de las ubicaciones no se encuentra en el lugar que debería. Y si está lejos de su lugar aproximadamente unos 200 mts pintar esa fila para poder reconocerla.

Ejemplo:
La app manda los siguientes datos `19.4320423,-99.1315439`, pero deberia encontrarme en `19.4276967,-99.1360661`, al estar alejado esa fila se pintaría de rojo.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme o decirme cómo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Dónde estás intentando calcularlo, en la app o en el servidor? ¿En qué lenguaje? ... "*si está lejos de su lugar*" <-- ¿siempre se calcula como la distancia a un punto X? ... ¿Podrías agregar las partes relevantes de tu código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la librería [GeoTools](https://github.com/thephpleague/geotools#geotools) para calcular la distancia

```
$geotools = new \League\Geotools\Geotools();
$coordA   = new \League\Geotools\Coordinate\Coordinate([48.8234055, 2.3072664]);
$coordB   = new \League\Geotools\Coordinate\Coordinate([43.296482, 5.36978]);
$distance = $geotools->distance()->setFrom($coordA)->setTo($coordB);
```

Y si la distancia es mayor a tu tolerancia, responder con un json que incluye el mensaje de advertencia.

Answer (score -1):

Entiendo que lo que tienes que hacer es calcular la distancia por cada punto que recibas de esta manera [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_del_haversine). Afortunadamente ya hay gente que lo tiene implementado en PHP: [Cálculo de la distancia en PHP en función de la latitud y longitud](http://assemblysys.com/es/calculo-de-la-distancia-en-funcion-de-la-latitud-y-longitud-en-php/).

Un consejo: Si tienes que calcular las distancias entre muchos puntos este proceso es costoso en tiempo, así que tendrías que buscar algún mecanismo (según tu sistema) para reducir el rango de valores de comparación y reducirlo a un conjunto de valores que puedas gestionar en un tiempo razonable.